Handle continuous parallel requests without blocking in Asyncio
I am new to python asyncio and have a slightly convoluted requirement. I have been going through the documentation for asyncio but have not found the right solution yet as I am unable to understand some aspects.
I have a script KafkaScript.py that reads from a kafka topic (streaming) and calls an API endpoint. The API will call a method method_A in another script ProcessingScript.py in parallel for each incoming request/kafka record.
method_A calls an asynchronous method_B which uses a globally defined ThreadPoolExecutor to call another asynchronous method_C using run_in_executor().
method_C return a string back to method_B which in turn must respond back to method_A.
Here is the script:
KafkaScript.py:
import requests

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in Kafka-Topic:
        # Use a new thread to call make API request for each kafka record
        response = requests.get(<url generated>) # i is passed as param

The API:
import ProcessingScript

@app.route('/v1/generate', methods = ['GET'])
def generate():
    data = request.args.get('data', type = str)
    response = ProcessingScript.method_A(data)
    return response
        

ProcessingScript.py:
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)

async def method_C(val):
        # Calls playwright to get content from a page which is a blocking call per thread
        return "processed:" + val


async def method_B(val):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        # For each parallel thread, call method_C, get the response without blocking other threads
        response = loop.run_in_executor(self.executor, asyncio.run, method_C(val))
        return response


def method_A(val):
        response = asyncio.run(method_B(val))
        return response

As I understand, method_B can receive the string from method_C only when I make a call such as this.
response = await loop.run_in_executor(self.executor, asyncio.run, method_C(val))

The problem with the await here is, although multiple threads are calling method_A, the await makes all threads wait for the first thread to have a response.
How do I ensure this in a thread safe manner where none of the parallel requests to method_A are blocked by others threads waiting for the response?

Why would you run an asyncio coroutine using loop.run_in_executor, which is meant to run non-asyncio functions that would otherwise block asyncio coroutines from running? Why don't you post something that is closer to your actual method_C function so we can see what it is actually doing. You are also showing a method_A (with incorrect indentation) that takes a content argument that is never used but referencing a val variable that is never defined. You need to clean up this post.

Hi @Booboo appreciate your comments. I have cleaned up the code wherever I can.  method_C uses a library to get content from a webpage which is a blocking call per thread. I am not specific about loop.run_in_executor if there is a better way to handle this multi threaded requirement.

Any code where you will call asyncio.run more than once is already incorrect. Passing asyncio.run to run_in_executor is really, very, bad.

This project needs to be reorganized -
My suggestion would be to bring everything under a single asyncio-loop (the way it is to be used, actually), including the code to listen for kafka messages.
That would be a 3-4 line function in a continous loop that would post the needed data back in an internal queue. Another async method with a continuous loop could see these messages and launch an asyncio task, that could then do call_in_executor for the final, non asychronous, code for each payload, if needed.
import asyncio, queue
import other_module

# if this does nothing async, it should not be an async method
def method_C(val):
    # Calls playwright to get content from a page which is a blocking call per thread
    return "processed:" + val

# your originak method_B serves nothing. 
# def method_B(...): ... 

def method_A(val, executor):
    response = await asyncio.run_in_executor(method_c, val)
    return response
    
###

interval = 0.1 

async def main():
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)
    tqueue = queue.Queue()
    aqueue = asyncio.Queue()
    responses = []
    tasks = set()
    try:
        while True:
            # you might want to put code to fetch more than a payload per cycle here
            task = asyncio.create_task(method_A(await aqueue.get(), executor))
            tasks.add(task)
            done, pending_tasks = asyncio.wait(tasks, tiemout=interval)
            
            for task in done:
                # you might want to check the task for Exceptions here.
                responses.append(done.result())
                # and you might also want to do other things to response instead
                # of simply adding them to  a list for consuming later.
            
            tasks = pending_tasks
            
            # you might want to add some condition/mechanism to stop the process. 
    finally:
        executor.close()
        other_module.stop_kafka_worker(tqueue)
    print(responses)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asuncio.run(main())

# ---------------------------------------------------
# kafka related code: "other_module"
    
    

import ProcessingScript
import sys
import threading

import queue

interval = 0.05  # wait 0.05 seconds for polling kafka queue again. change as desided.
_sentinel = object()
stop_kafka = False

async def kafkabroker(tqueue, aqueue):
    while True:
        try:
            payload = tqueue.get_nowait()
        except queue.Empty:
            pass
        else:
            if payload is _sentinel:
                break
            await aqueue.put(payload)
        await asyncio.sleep(interval)
        
def kafka_fetcher(tqueue):
    # you may want to add some mechanism for shutting down this listenet - 
    # the "for x in message_topic" you written have to be changed for something else.
    for msg in kafka_topic:
        if stop_kafka:
            break  #this will stop, but will only be checked when a new kafka msg arrives
        tqueue.put(msg)

def start_kafka_worker(tqueue):
    global kafka_worker_thread
    kafka_worker_thread = threading.Thread(target=kafka_fetcher(tqueue)
    kafka_worker_thread.start()
    

def stop_kafka_worker(tqueue):
    global stop_kafka
    stop_kafka =  True
    tqueue.put(_sentinel)





I would really appreciate it, if you could help me with some code reference or a sample piece of code in addition to your explanation if possible. As I have mentioned already, I am new to asyncio and its capabilities.

Additionally, what if we cannot bring the kafka script into the asyncio loop. The reason I have added the reading of kafka record as a separate script is to show that that this task is abstracted from the actual processing task and is not an asyncio based script.

The afka specifc code can run in a worker thread, and an asyncio task in the main thread would just pick the payloads and post them for other asyncio tasks

I get that. The problem here is that the kafka requests tasks is abstracted. You can think of this as a case where for abstracted code read from a kafka topic and for each record, will make an API call. The API script for each incoming request will call method_A. It is not possible to touch the Kafka script.

I've added some code now. Code like this is usually have to take care of some conditions, and lots of clean-up when things don't go the wanted way, or even to stop everything in a clean way. So I posted a bare skeleton with the correct way to use asyncio, at last.

the parts I placed in "Kafka code" can be brought to the main module. But you'd need at least a funciton on the "untouchable script" that could be run in a separate thread - if the code is really at top level as it is, and can't be modified, but for calling method_A, there are other arrangements needed. I'd prefer to fix that as a consulting job than trying to write generic advice for a very specific situation you have there.
